# Linq group by and get count of occurence

Tags: c#, linq

I need to get topic name and number of times (count) a given topic occurs.

Example:

```
Name: John
Topic: X, Y, Z => these are List<string>

Name: Bob
Topic: Y

Name: Suzy
Topic: Y, Z

Should generate output:
X: 1
Y: 3
Z: 2
```

I've tried this but it doesn't return correct result:

```
var result = from r in items
                         orderby r.Topic
                         group r by r.Topic
                into grp
                         select new { key = grp.Key, cnt = grp.Count() };
```

Comment: "it doesn't return correct result" - that's never enough information. What *does* it do? Can you provide a [mcve] demonstrating this? (We can't even tell what the data looks like in code at the moment.)

Comment: What is the point of sorting before grouping?

Comment: @EricLippert It affects the order of the items within the group, as `GroupBy` ensures that items in a group are in the same relative order that they were in the original sequence.  At least for the `IEnumerable` implementation.  Of course this code doesn't seem to care about the order of the items in the group, but it's at least *sometimes* sensible.

Comment: @Servy I should have been more specific. What is the point of ordering before grouping on the same criterion? If the goal is to be sorted by group key then do the grouping first.

Comment: Can you at least specify what are the results of the query you attempted to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can flatten the contained collection with another `from`:

```
var result = from r in lineItems
             from t in r.Topic  // List<string>
             group t by t into grp
             orderby grp.Key
             select new { key = grp.Key, cnt = grp.Count() };
```

Comment: The query is more efficient if the orderby is in the continuation query. Do you see why?

Comment: @EricLippert: thanks for noting, yes, probably less to sort

Answer (score 0):

I like to do this using SelectMany( to flatten the inner collection)
Just another way to do this

```
var result = items.SelectMany((w) => w.Topic)
                    .GroupBy((q) => q)
                    .Select((p) => new { Grp = p.Key, Cnt = p.Count() })
                    .OrderBy((g) => g.Cnt);
```